# Solution to compilation error on trying to copy text into a file using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am a beginner with Selenium webdrivers. I'm getting a compilation error with the below code..Can anyone assist?

I am trying to copy a message into a file instead of showing it on the console.

```
testResultFile="C:\\CopyMessageTest.txt";
File file = new file(testResultFile).canWrite();
FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file); 
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fis);
System.setOut(out);
System.out.println("----------Sucessfully Logged In ----------------");
```

The error is on the line

```
File file = new file(testResultFile).canWrite();
```

Answer (score 0):

new file(testResultFile).canWrite(); will return the Boolean value to check can we writable or not. You have to use in this way to check that

```
boolean  bool = new file(testResultFile).canWrite();
```

To write into file simply you can use

```
   FileOutputStream fop = null;
    File file;
    String content = "This is the text content";

    try {

        file = new File("c:/newfile.txt");
        fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        // get the content in bytes
        byte[] contentInBytes = content.getBytes();

        fop.write(contentInBytes);
        fop.flush();
        fop.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Updating with another way as per comment

```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.PrintStream;

 public class PrintTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    File file=new File("C:\\CopyMessageTest.txt"); //my file where i want to write

    boolean bool = file.canWrite(); //cross checking file can be writable or not

    if(bool==false){

        file.setWritable(true); //if not writable then set it to writable
    }

    FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file); 
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fis);
    System.setOut(out);
    System.out.println("----------Sucessfully Logged In ----------------");



    }

 }
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Hi Murali, First of all thank you for your inputs .What i am trying to achieve is the message "Successfully Logged in" getting saved in a file. i am trying to first check the boolean value for                      "boolean bool = new file (testResultFile).canWrite();" and then trying to FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file); 
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fis);
System.setOut(out);
System.out.println("----------Sucessfully Logged In ----------------");         It still has same error on the file into the boolean validation.

Comment: @Gauravj make sure that you have writable permissions in C driver. Generally in corporate office we don't have write permissions in C. If so please try in D or some other location where you have write permissions

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes that you have done in the code. In the first line you did not mention what type of data it is, it should be a String. In the second line, the object that you are creating should be of type File, you mentioned file, also, the return type of canWrite() method is a boolean, if you still want to use that mention, define it explicitly in the next line. see the corrected code below.

```
    String testResultFile="C:\\CopyMessageTest.txt";
    File file = new File(testResultFile);
    file.canWrite();
    FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file); 
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fis);
    System.setOut(out);
    System.out.println("----------Sucessfully Logged In ----------------");
```

Comment: I Tried this solution, it gives me Access Deined message :-(

Comment: That is strange error. Check if the file is open when you are running the above code. The file should not be opened when writing to the file.